RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding encryption using flutter pointycastle and encrypt library
I tried implementing RSA encryption using pointycastle and encrypt library exactly just like from the documentation. It works but when I tested it in like an online website like devgland.com it gives a Padding error in decryption.
Here's the code that encrypts the string
String rsaEncrypt(String dataToEncrypt) {
  final publicKey = RSAKeyParser().parse(publicKeyStr) as RSAPublicKey;

  final engine = OAEPEncoding.withSHA256(RSAEngine());

  engine.init(
    true,
    PublicKeyParameter<RSAPublicKey>(publicKey),
  ); // true=encrypt

  return base64Encode(
    _processInBlocks(
      engine,
      Uint8List.fromList(dataToEncrypt.codeUnits),
    ),
  );
}

Uint8List _processInBlocks(AsymmetricBlockCipher engine, Uint8List input) {
  final numBlocks = input.length ~/ engine.inputBlockSize +
      ((input.length % engine.inputBlockSize != 0) ? 1 : 0);

  final output = Uint8List(numBlocks * engine.outputBlockSize);

  var inputOffset = 0;
  var outputOffset = 0;
  while (inputOffset < input.length) {
    final chunkSize = (inputOffset + engine.inputBlockSize <= input.length)
        ? engine.inputBlockSize
        : input.length - inputOffset;

    outputOffset += engine.processBlock(
        input, inputOffset, chunkSize, output, outputOffset);

    inputOffset += chunkSize;
  }

  return (output.length == outputOffset)
      ? output
      : output.sublist(0, outputOffset);
}

Output:
devgland.com error output

Presumably different digests for MGF1. PointyCastle implicitly uses the OAEP digest also as MGF1 digest (this can be changed by explicitly specifying the MGF1 digest after OAEPEncoding.init()). DevGlan presumably uses the SunJCE provider if RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding is chosen, which applies SHA-1 for the MGF1 digest.

Thank you for your response. You're right PointyCastle also uses the OAEP digest for MGF1 digest.
